# Silverlight LoadComponent from string

Tags: silverlight, xamlreader

Welcome all

Basically, in Silverlight 4 or 5, I would like to call `Application.LoadComponent()` for a given valid xaml content. The problem is, that this xaml is dynamically created, and is not present in resource available for URI.

Normally, this would work:

```
System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, 
    new System.Uri("/TestApp;component/MainPage.xaml"));
```

but I need something like:

```
string s = "{some xaml}";
System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, s);
```

I cannot use `XamlReader.Load()`, because my xaml contains `x:Class="..."`, which is not acceptable by this method.

How can I go on? 
I was thinking to put the string into `MergedDictionary` or something, but then, how to make the URI to point it?

Comment: is there really nobody there to give a tip?

Comment: well, i think it is e perfect question without an answer... :)